# I trying to use babel and react but I keep getting an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I'm trying to use babel and react but every time I open the browser I keep getting a error in the console "Uncaught Error: Module name "react" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])". When this error happens nothing renderers to the screen. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="us">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js">
</script> <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js"></script>
<script src="./app.js" type="text/babel"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render<<p>Main page</p>);
```

Comment: Please post code as text instead of images. Images can be [annoying for some users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had a duplicate of requireJS in my `node_modules` folder, I had to uninstall and reinstall requireJS. I could of also did **`npm dedupe`** instead of reinstalling it. Afterwards it worked fine.